# Preventing Chrome from keeping my history

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I would like Chrome to stop keeping my browsing history. I am familiar with incognito mode but would like to retain everything from my browsing *except* my history (e.g., Incognito mode deletes cookies which I want to retain.) Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way from Chrome itself (even with an extension: I don't think extensions can run a hook when the browser exits). But it's easy to do from the outside: instead of launching Chrome, launch a script that runs Chrome, then deletes the history.

For best privacy, put the history on a RAM filesystem (make the `History` file in your profile a symbolic link pointing into the RAM filesystem).

Comment: There is a way now: https://superuser.com/a/1469116/431826

Answer (score 1):

As of now you'll have to use  Clear Browsing Data ( Chrome Menu → Tools → Clear browsing data )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, I have this script below that may help.

Usage: save the script below in a "del_chrome_hist.bat" file, ensure Chrome is totally closed (no chrome.exe in your TaskMan) and then run it with admin privileges  :

---

```
ECHO deleting chrome history
set ChromeDataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*History*.*">nul 2>&1    

set ChromeDataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*History*.*">nul 2>&1
ECHO deleting chrome history DONE
```

Furthermore, you can create a task schedule to run this script on Windows start-up.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to keep Chrome from logging your history, without using incognito mode, go to `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`, and change all of the history files to read only. just right click on them, choose properties, click the "read only" radio, and hit ok. there should only be a few - "history", 1-3 files labelled "history index .....", "history provider cache", and "history-journal". set them all to read only and it won't record your history as you browse. still haven't figured out how to stop it from recording omnibox text

Answer (score 0):

There is now an extension which stops chrome from recording History... https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-history/ljamgkbcojbnmcaonjokopmcblmmpfch#