# Disable history in Chromium?

Tags: history, chromium

Is there really no way at all to make Chromium clear browsing history on exit? The closest way I know is to use incognito mode, which is fine except for the inconvenience of opening the browser, opening an incognito tab, then closing the original tab. Furthermore, when I click on a link in a different program, it will open in a regular tab, not an incognito tab, if the browser is not running.

Answer (score 4):

#### For clearing cookies on exit:

- Enable: `Settings`->`Privacy and security`->`Site settings`->`Cookies`->`Keep local data until you quit your browser`

(You can always exclude sites from this rule, down in the section: `Sites that can always use cookies`. E.g. exclude `stackoverflow.com` to stay logged-in between browser restarts )

#### For clearing browsing history on exit:

You need to change the value of policy setting: `SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled`

Depending on the OS the location and value of the setting changes.

**windows/chromeOS:**

Set **Registry** value  `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled` to `0x00000001`

**linux**

```bsh
#1.  chose directory 
#based on this doc: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start
# chrome
cd /etc/opt/chrome/
# chromium
cd /etc/chromium/

# however on my ubuntu: 
cd /etc/chromium-browser/


# 2.
mkdir -p policies/managed
cd policies/managed

# become su
sudo -i

# 3. Just edit a new or existing json file (e.g. custom_policy.json) 
# and add the key-value pair: {"SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled" : true}
vim custom_policy.json

# 3 Alternatively from the command line 
[ -f custom_policy.json ] || echo "{}" > custom_policy.json
jq '.SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled = true' custom_policy.json|sponge custom_policy.json

# 4. remove write permission (otherwise it wont' work.)
chmod -w custom_policy.json
chmod go-w .
```

**mac**

For mac follow [this guide](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/mac-quick-start). The corresponding value should be set to: `<true />`

---

Then after restarting your browser you should see the loaded policy with values under: **chrome://policy**

In the (3 dots) menu section also you will now see the message: `Managed by your organization`

#### manually clearing history and cookes:

`Ctrl-Shift-Delete` -> Select options to clear-> Press `clear data`

LINKS:

- https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled
- https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled

Answer (score 2):

I see 3 ways:

1. The simple way is to use the **Incognito mode automatically**.
   Add `--incognito` flag at the end of the Chromium shortcut and restart the browser. This way works on Chromium and Google Chrome.

[image: Incognito mode in Chromium browser]

Now, you browse in Incognito mode all the time.

2. Use a **browser extension** like [Click&Clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod) and close Chromium with it.
3. **Clean history manually** with clearBrowserData. Just type `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` in the [address bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bar) (omnibox) before to close Chromium.